# call external js function within razor

Tags: javascript, razor, web

I have this code:

```
Html.RequiresJs("~/Scripts/site/scripts.app.js", 5);
@{

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringQueryElement) && !upcoming.Any())
    {   
        <script type="text/javascript">
            X();
        </script>
    }
}
```

Inside **scripts.app.js** file I have a function X() which I want to call out when my if statement is true. How I call it? Because the syntax I have now does not work.
Did some debugging and I can see that IF statement works correctly. The only question is how do I call my function that is stored in **scripts.app.js**.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Does `Html.RequireJs()` inject the scripts at `<head>` section? If not, where does it inject?

Comment: This line injects it at the bottom of the body. after footer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comment stated, your scripts.app.js is injected just before `</body>`. This means the script's functions are available **after** it is evaluated by the browser. Because you try to run your script **before** that has happened, it won't detect your `X()` function.

Use the `document ready` to make sure all scripts are evaluated:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringQueryElement) && !upcoming.Any())
    {   
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                X();
            });
        </script>
    }
}
```

(Assuming you're using jQuery)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I can not believe I missed it. :)